# Angularjs with packery.js draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I was able to get packery.js library working in Angularjs based on the solution provided in  [Angularjs with Packery.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498174/angularjs-with-packery-js/21288318)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div ng-repeat="item in test" danny-packery>
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var dannyPackery = app.directive('dannyPackery', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('Running dannyPackery linking function!');
            if($rootScope.packery === undefined || $rootScope.packery === null){
                console.log('making packery!');
                $rootScope.packery = new Packery(element[0].parentElement, {columnWidth: '.item'});
                $rootScope.packery.bindResize();
                $rootScope.packery.appended(element[0]);
                $rootScope.packery.items.splice(1,1); // hack to fix a bug where the first element was added twice in two different positions
            }
            else{
                $rootScope.packery.appended(element[0]);
            }
            $rootScope.packery.layout();
        }
    };
}]);
```

How can I add the draggable options to the above code? The jquery code for draggable option is provided here http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html. Any comment is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [this](https://github.com/SunGard-Labs/angular-packery) library and it works fine.